# FullText In Microsoft Sql Server - Returning exactly word

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Can anyone tell me how to query a fulltext table in Sql Server, and get only exactly matches? Example:

I have those records in a table named "Items":

> Bath
>   Bathroom
>   Test
>   Testing

I need to query for Bath and get only 1 record, "bath", excluding the word Bathroom. The same to the word "Test", wich in my context is different to "Testing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM [itens] AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE([itens], *, 'Bath') AS KEY_TBL
   ON FT_TBL.unique_key_column = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

---

**or**

```
SELECT columnname
FROM [itens]
WHERE CONTAINS(somecolumn, 'Bath')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

---

Just noticed the updated questions (*formatting applied*).
If you column holds keywords (*single word*) then you could just select `column = 'keyword'`.

```
SELECT columnname
FROM [itens]
WHERE somecolumn = 'Bath'
```

Comment: SELECT columnname
FROM [itens]
WHERE CONTAINS(somecolumn, 'Bath')
Thats what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

are you searching for bath and test in one query or in different? 
if in single, then one of the solutions i see is:

```
select top 1 from table where column like '[., ]bath[., ]%'
```

if in different, then union a series of such select's

Comment: ... where column like '[., !?;]bath[., !?;]%' and the ... will be stopped by [.] symbol. real regular exressions may look much more horrible

Comment: Yes, but the point is that you should not have to predict all possible characters that define a word boundary. The OP uses full-text-search which allows for this automatically.

Comment: i don't deny this. i didn't say that was the only solution.

Comment: @heximal, not bashing at you.. i, too, was just trying to indicate that it has some restrictions as-is..

Comment: i think some restrictions for keywords count must present. what if i decide to send search request with search phrase that contains one thousand keywords?

Comment: This solution works for any table, nevertheless, it doesn't use the fulltext index, so is not really optimal.